# trying to validate string as boolean Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm currently trying to validate if a string is exactly true or false as I'm building a spreadsheet importer using CF10.

My users will either enter in one of the following.

1. NULL, which will equate to false
2. TRUE which obviously equates to true
3. FALSE which again will equate to false.

I'm trying to use the `isValid('boolean',variable.data)` to validate if the data is in fact a boolean string or not. However after reading quite a few posts I can see that it will validate `true` if its a positive number and `false` if it is a negative one etc.

I'm wondering if anyone has an easy fix to getting boolean validation working for strings easily ? Is this more a regular expressions scenario to make it work properly ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you mean the literal string "NULL", one option is using list functions. Search a list of allowed values, ie "true,false,null". If the entry is found, it is valid:

```
<cfif listFindNoCase("true,false,null", theValue)>
    this is a valid boolean value
<cfelse>
    not found. do something here...
</cfif>
```

Then a simple [string comparison](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f83.html) would return `false` for everything other than the literal string "true":

```
  isTrue = compareNoCase(e, "true") eq 0 ? true : false`
```

Comment: is `isTrue = compareNoCase(e, "true") eq 0 ? true : false` any different to `isTrue = e eq 'true' ? true : false` I know which I prefer :P

Comment: Yep, it is different ;-) When `e = "yes"`, the latter still returns `true`. Of course if you are talking about the *validated* input - then you are right, it ultimately makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to evaluate whether a string is exactly "true" or "false", then you are not doing a boolean comparison, you are doing a string comparison.

So to that end, you'd be wanting to use [`compare()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Compare) or [`compareNoCase()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/CompareNoCase) (depending on how rigid you need to be).

Comment: Darn, turn away for a minute ... You beat me to it!

Comment: Heh. Sorry mate. Hey Leigh, do you exist on Twitter or outside of this particular website?

Comment: Yeah I am on Twitter, but only once in a blue moon. Not much time for it most days.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do some logic or am I missing something.

```
<cfset booleanResult = enteredValue eq 'TRUE' ? true : false />
```

Comment: FWIW, that would also return true for "yes" and "1".

Comment: My users will either enter in one of the following.

NULL, which will equate to false
TRUE which obviously equates to true
FALSE which again will equate to false.

Thus if they are the only things that can be entered, it will work

Comment: Yep. Actually I posted that before I realized he was ultimately asking was how to perform an `IsValid` like "test", rather than how to convert the input to: `true/value`. (That said, since he did mention similar issues with `IsValid`, it probably was not a bad idea to mention the same thing happens anytime you perform a non-string comparison. Just for the archives.)

Comment: Ack.. darn typos. That should be: "convert the input to: true / **false** "